# nginx not listening to port 80

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I've just installed a Ubuntu 12.04 server and nginx 1.2.7, removed `default` from sites-enabled and added my own file into `sites-available` and symlink at `sites-enabled`. Then restarted nginx.

**Problem:** However going to the URL does not load the site. `netstat -nlp | grep nginx` and `netstat -nlp | grep 80` both returns no results! `lsof -i :80` also returns nothing. A `dig` from another server returns the correct ip address so it shouldn't be a DNS problem. I was able to connect to apache which I have now stopped its service. nginx logs also show nothing.

How should I troubleshoot this problem?

**/etc/nginx/site-available/mysite.com**

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name www.mysite.com mysite.com *.mysite.com;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    root /var/www/mysite/public;

    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args ;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
    }

}
```

Comment: anything in the logs?

Comment: Is it actually running? Did you start it with `sudo`?

Comment: Please don't downvote a question just because you don't know the answer.

I'm having the same issue. Nothing in access logs... it's listening on *:80. No error in the debug error log. And yes, @DondiMichaelStroma it is running. (lol).

Comment: did you find out what the problem was? I'm having similar issue...

Comment: I was using centos-6. it doesn't have site-enabled etc. I have to remove server entry /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf and add nginx.conf in same directory.

Comment: same issue for port 80, but nginx listen on other port is working...can anyone help

Comment: Helped me as well. I was being sloppy about my linking and server blocks thanks @Nyxynyx

Answer (score 140):

I had this same problem, the solution was that I had not symlinked my siteconf file correctly. Try running `vim /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com`—can you get to it? I was getting "Permission Denied."

If not run:

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com
```

Comment: This fixed it for me! Apparently when you don't type in the full filename in the second argument, i.e. `ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mysite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`, it creates sort of a fake symlink, which nginx chokes on. Strange, but true.

Comment: This was the solution for me too. Stumbled upon this thread while googling for answers.

Comment: This was also a solution for me. I have been running in circles for hours trying to fix an nginx install. Bravo, ye gentleman!

Comment: Thanks guys!  I realized I had done something similar when creating a symlink earlier today.  Recreated it with the full path and bingo, nginx loaded the config for my new site.

Comment: Thank you thank you. I was pulling my hair out for the last 2 hours!!

Comment: Thank you! own you 1MM of donnuts!

Comment: Thank you thank you! Been banging my head against the keyboard for hours trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: Thank you for this, it was driving crazy. The tutorial I was following actually had a relative symlink.

Comment: 1 mistake, 9 hours

Comment: Damn this was extremely aggravating! THANK YOU!

Comment: Yep, same issue and same solution! Remember to reload the nginx config after the change. ``sudo service nginx reload``

Comment: THIS was literally what brought back my production site - so thank you!!

Comment: This also saved my ass. Just saying.

Answer (score 36):

If your logs are silent on the issue, you may not be including the sites-enabled directory. One simple way to tell that the site is being loaded is to set the error/access log path within your server block to a unique path, reload nginx, and check if the files are created.

Ensure the following include directive exists within the http context in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf.

```
http {
  ...
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Comment: Such a simple thing to miss. Thank you for mentioning it!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You save my day

Comment: In some versions of nginx you have to write `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;`

Answer (score 13):

I've found it helpful to approach debugging nginx with the following steps:

**1**... Make sure nginx is running.

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

**2**... Check for processes already bound to the port in question.

```
lsof -n -i:80
```

**3**... Make sure nginx has been reloaded.

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo nginx -s reload
```

> On Mac, `brew services restart nginx` is **not** sufficient to reload nginx.

**4**... Try creating simple responses manually to make sure your location path isn't messed up. This is especially helpful when problems arise while using `proxy_pass` to forward requests to other running apps.

```
location / {
    add_header Content-Type text/html;
    return 200 'Here I am!';
}
```

Comment: I tried using `lsof -nP` to check if nginx was listening. Only nginx does not show up in lsof, only in `netstat -van`. Maybe it's because nginx does not open sockets like a file but using special async io calls?

Comment: `brew services * nginx` works when I prefix `sudo ...`. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38040732/homebrew-nginx-not-running-but-says-it-is-in-brew-services

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem, I got a `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error when connecting over HTTP, but fine over HTTPS. Ran `netstat -tulpn` and saw nginx not binding to port 80 for IPv4. Done everything described here. Turned out to be something ***very*** stupid:

**Make sure the `sites-available` file with the `default_server` is actually enabled.**

Hope this saved some other poor idiot out there some time.

Answer (score 5):

You are probably binding nginx to port 80 twice. Is that your full config file? Don't you have another statement listening to port 80?

Comment: I was trying to host GitLab on port 80 but found out there was also a "default" site bound to that port. After removing the latter my GitLab host was running fine.

Comment: @riezebosch removing that site's configuration should work, but you can also use different server_names in case you want to listen to port 80 multiple times

Comment: @Andres - Upvoted your comment , thanks this was helpful.

Comment: nginx has a default site in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled, I removed it and now it works!

Answer (score 3):

A semi-colon `;` missing in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` for exemple on the line before `include /etc/nginx/servers-enabled/*;` can just bypass this intruction and `nginx -t` check will be successful anyway.

So just check that all instructions in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` are ended with a semi-colon `;`.

Answer (score 3):

I had faced the same problem over the server, here I am listing the how I had solved it :

**Step 1 :: Installing the Ngnix**

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install nginx
```

**Step 2 – Adjusting the Firewall**

```
sudo ufw app list
```

You should get a listing of the application profiles:

> `Output
>   Available applications:
>     Nginx Full
>     Nginx HTTP
>     Nginx HTTPS
>     OpenSSH`

As you can see, there are three profiles available for Nginx:

**Nginx Full:** This profile opens both port 80 (normal, unencrypted web traffic) and port 443 (TLS/SSL encrypted traffic)

**Nginx HTTP:** This profile opens only port 80 (normal, unencrypted web traffic)

**Nginx HTTPS:** This profile opens only port 443 (TLS/SSL encrypted traffic)

Since I haven’t configured SSL for our server yet in this guide, we will only need to allow traffic on port 80.You can enable this by typing:

```
sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'
```

You can verify the change by typing:

```
sudo ufw status
```

**Step 3 – Checking your Web Server**

```
systemctl status nginx
```

Now Check port 80 , It worked for me hope will work for you as well.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74912191/can-access-django-admin-through-nginx-port-80-but-not-other-ports  
I am having this issue, can you help me explain

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked if your nginx binary really exists? please check if

```
#whereis nginx
```

outputs the binary path and check this path with your init script from /etc/init.d/nginx. e.g.

```
DAEMON=/usr/sbin/nginx
```

(In my init script "test -x $DAEMON || exit 0" is invoked and in any case this script returned nothing - my binary was completely missing)

Answer (score 1):

While we all think we don't make silly mistakes, we do.

So, if you are looking into NGINX issues and all signs are showing it should work then you should take a step away from the files and look downstream.

System Firewall, Hardware Firewall, Nat router/firewall.

For myself this issue was my router, I run a home lab and so I can access services behind my router from afar I use NGINX to reverse proxy as my router only handles incoming based on IP and doesn't do any handling of hostnames, I'm sure this is all fairly normal.

In any case my issue cropped up as I was securing my network a few days ago, removing some port forwarding that isnt needed any longer and I accidentally removed port 80.

Yes it was as simple as forwarding that port again to NGINX and all was fixed.

I will now walk away with my head hung in extreme shame though I leave this answer to show my gratitude to the people in this thread that lead me to find my own error.

So thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case those network command's outputs showed nginx was correctly binding to port 80, yet the ports weren't externally accessible or visible with `nmap`.

While I suspected a firewall,  it turns out that old `iptables` rules on the machine were redirecting traffic from those ports and conflicting with nginx. Use `sudo iptables-save` to view all currently applicable rules.

Answer (score -1):

I am facing the same issue. Just reload the nginx help me

```
sudo nginx -t
```

If you got error then just delete the log.txt file
then,

```
sudo nginx -s reload
```