# Rails app error connection refused - nginx & puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, puma

Following this guide - https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/deploying-a-rails-app-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-capistrano-nginx-and-puma
yesterday I deployed an application successfully. Today I tried to do just the same and when entering the IP, I receive ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.

Some research led me to this article https://askubuntu.com/questions/646293/open-port-80-on-ubuntu-server
and usage of netstat-command:

Server 1 (where everything is fine)

```
netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Server 2 (where I can't access my app)

```
netstat -lnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5432          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

Apparently there is no port 80 open.

My puma is running:

```
cap production puma:status
DEBUG [d1e4089c]    Puma is started
```

Nginx is running too:

```
sudo service nginx status
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2015-09-23 13:59:56 EDT; 17min ago
  Process: 7541 ExecStop=/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /run/nginx.pid (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7573 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 7572 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 7576 (nginx)
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─7576 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           ├─7577 nginx: worker process
           ├─7578 nginx: worker process
           ├─7579 nginx: worker process
           └─7580 nginx: worker process

Sep 23 13:59:56 rails.projects systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Sep 23 13:59:56 rails.projects systemd[1]: Failed to read PID from file /run/nginx.pid: Invalid argument
Sep 23 13:59:56 rails.projects systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

This is my config/nginx.conf:

```
upstream puma {
  server unix:///home/deploy/apps/furnitureapp/shared/tmp/sockets/furnitureapp-puma.sock;
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server deferred;
  # server_name example.com;

  root /home/deploy/apps/furnitureapp/current/public;
  access_log /home/deploy/apps/furnitureapp/current/log/nginx.access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/apps/furnitureapp/current/log/nginx.error.log info;

  location ^~ /assets/ {
    gzip_static on;
    expires max;
    add_header Cache-Control public;
  }

  try_files $uri/index.html $uri @puma;
  location @puma {
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_pass http://puma;
  }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
  client_max_body_size 10M;
  keepalive_timeout 10;
}
```

If it matters, here my config/deploy.rb:

```
# Change these
server 'myip', port: 4014, roles: [:web, :app, :db], primary: true

set :repo_url,        'git://github.com/mohnstrudel/furnitureapp.git'
set :application,     'furnitureapp'
set :user,            'deploy'
set :puma_threads,    [4, 16]
set :puma_workers,    0

# Don't change these unless you know what you're doing
set :pty,             true
set :use_sudo,        false
set :stage,           :production
set :deploy_via,      :remote_cache
set :deploy_to,       "/home/#{fetch(:user)}/apps/#{fetch(:application)}"
set :puma_bind,       "unix://#{shared_path}/tmp/sockets/#{fetch(:application)}-puma.sock"
set :puma_state,      "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"
set :puma_pid,        "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.pid"
set :puma_access_log, "#{release_path}/log/puma.error.log"
set :puma_error_log,  "#{release_path}/log/puma.access.log"
set :ssh_options,     { forward_agent: true, user: fetch(:user), keys: %w(~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) }
set :puma_preload_app, true
set :puma_worker_timeout, nil
set :puma_init_active_record, true  # Change to false when not using ActiveRecord

## Defaults:
# set :scm,           :git
# set :branch,        :master
# set :format,        :pretty
# set :log_level,     :debug
# set :keep_releases, 5

## Linked Files & Directories (Default None):
# set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
# set :linked_dirs,  %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

namespace :puma do
  desc 'Create Directories for Puma Pids and Socket'
  task :make_dirs do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/sockets -p"
      execute "mkdir #{shared_path}/tmp/pids -p"
    end
  end

  before :start, :make_dirs
end

namespace :deploy do
  desc "Make sure local git is in sync with remote."
  task :check_revision do
    on roles(:app) do
      unless `git rev-parse HEAD` == `git rev-parse origin/master`
        puts "WARNING: HEAD is not the same as origin/master"
        puts "Run `git push` to sync changes."
        exit
      end
    end
  end

  desc 'Initial Deploy'
  task :initial do
    on roles(:app) do
      before 'deploy:restart', 'puma:start'
      invoke 'deploy'
    end
  end

  desc 'Restart application'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app), in: :sequence, wait: 5 do
      invoke 'puma:restart'
    end
  end

  before :starting,     :check_revision
  after  :finishing,    :compile_assets
  after  :finishing,    :cleanup
  after  :finishing,    :restart
end

# ps aux | grep puma    # Get puma pid
# kill -s SIGUSR2 pid   # Restart puma
# kill -s SIGTERM pid   # Stop puma
```

Can someone point me into the right direction? How can I open port 80 (google doesn't help much in that direction)?

Answer (score 2):

After a night of search I found this SO question which is 100% my problem - [nginx not listening to port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021481/nginx-not-listening-to-port-80)

So basically I screwed up the symlinking 
( this step in the tutorial: )

```
On the Droplet, Symlink the nginx.conf to the sites-enabled directory:

sudo rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo ln -nfs "/home/deploy/apps/appname/current/config/nginx.conf" "/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/appname"
```

Removing /etc/nginx/sites/enabled/default again and relinking did the job!