# Homebrew Nginx not running but says it is in brew services

Tags: nginx, homebrew, osx-elcapitan

I have OSX El Capitan. I installed Nginx-Full via homebrew. I am supposed to be able to start and stop services with

> brew services Nginx-Full Start

I run that command and it seems to start no problem. I check the running services with

> brew services list

That indicates that the Nginx-Full services is running. When i run

> htop

to look at everything that is running Nginx does not show up and the server is not handling requests.

Answer (score 27):

## nginx is failing to launch because of an error, but brew-services is not communicating that to you.

Running it with `sudo`, as other users have suggested, is just masking the problem. If you just run `nginx` directly, you may see that there is actually a configuration or permissions issue that is causing nginx to abort. In my case, it was because it couldn't write to the error log:

```
nginx: [alert] could not open error log file: open() "/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
2020/04/02 13:11:53 [warn] 19989#0: the "user" directive makes sense only if the master process runs with super-user privileges, ignored in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:2
2020/04/02 13:11:53 [emerg] 19989#0: open() "/usr/local/var/log/nginx/error.log" failed (13: Permission denied)
```

The last error is causing nginx to fail to launch. You can make yourself the owner of the logs with:

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/var/log/nginx/`

This *should* cause subsequent config errors to be written to the error log, even if homebrew services is not reporting them in stderr/stdout for now.

I've opened an issue about this: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-services/issues/215

The log path may not the same for everyone. You can check the path to log file by checking the config file `/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. You can find a line like:
`error_log  /Users/myusername/somepath/nginx.log;`. Change the chown command above accordingly. If even this didn't solve the problem, you may have to do the same for any other log files specified in the `server` blocks in your nginx configuration

Comment: This worked perfectly. Instead of forcing it with sudo, you should fix the underlying issue and run it under your own user. Thanks.

Comment: I am experiencing a similar issue but with Postgres. How can I find out why there is an error?

Comment: I'm having the same situation but the `chown` command didn't make any difference

Comment: In my case, I had soft link to /var/log/nginx but OS update removed it. Relinking to the same directory solved the issue.

Comment: For me `sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/homebrew/var/log/nginx/` did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Try launching it with "sudo", even if the formula say

> The default port has been set in /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf to 8080 so that
>   nginx can run without sudo.

```
sudo brew services Nginx-Full start
```

Comment: First stop it and then do with `sudo`.

Comment: Never use sudo to force this to start. alexw's answer below is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

this worked for me:

`sudo brew services start nginx`

Comment: Never use sudo to force this to start. alexw's answer below is the way to go.

Comment: Because port 80! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Running `sudo nginx` worked for me, it initially gave some error stating certain file in certain directory is missing, creating that file, and then another file is asked for to be created and then it runs properly.

I had similar problem, running it `brew services start nginx` used to show nginx running.

but `brew services list` used to show error.

running with `sudo nginx` solved my issue

Answer (score 0):

this works for me:

start nginx:

```
sudo nginx
```

stop nginx:

```
sudo nginx -s stop
```