# Host machine cannot access nginx virtual hosts on the guest machine

Tags: windows, nginx, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

Question: how to create simple nginx config that will read folders structure as domains (test.local, myblog.local) and shows the page from this folders, including PHP?

Information:
Windows 10 x64 build
Vagrant 1.9.5
VirtualBox 5.0.22 (latest)
Guest OS: Ubuntu Xenial x64 latest

So, i want to create simple nginx config, that will recreate folder structure. See 
[my config file](https://pastebin.com/xat1LMSM) on pastebin.

Also here is a [Vagrantfile](https://pastebin.com/RQmkzL7m) config, which use SMB to mount a folder.

The structure of folders:

```
├───devhost.local
│   ├───log
│   └───public
│           index.html
│           index.php
│
└───test.local
    ├───log
    └───public
            index.html
```

The rights for files and folders for devhost:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ls -la /var/www/html/devhost.local/
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu www-data    0 Jun  7 11:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu www-data 4096 Jun  7 12:44 ..
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu www-data    0 Jun  7 11:17 log
drwxr-xr-x 2 ubuntu www-data    0 Jun  6 14:13 public
```

My hosts file in Windows:

```
192.168.33.10   devhost.local
```

So, when i have default config in my `sites-enabled` folder i can open guest machine through `192.168.33.10` and i see html page of nginx, but when i remove this default config and enable my wildcard config (see link my config file) so i cannot access my domains. The `sudo nginx -t` says that everything is ok, also i tried to restart my guest machine, reload/restart nginx service. Also, i disable Windows 10 Firewall (i dont know if its disabled fully, but says that its disabled). Also, the log files is empty and even not created, both access log and error log.

Where is my mistake? If need more information, please, ask me, i will give.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot achieve this without dnsmasq or manually add every domain to hosts file

Comment: Yes, i add manualy each domain in hosts file, this will not work?

Answer (score 0):

following nginx setup should help.

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  root /var/www/html/$host;
  index index.html index.php;
  location ~ \.php {
    # ... fastcgi details
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is the same. Chrome say that ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. Also, i disable ufw, but it not helps to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

First of all, when i keep only one file with config, my nginx doesnt listen port 80, i check `sudo netstat -ntlp | grep LISTEN` but there wasnt port 80. So i Google, and found another question on stackoverflow (see link at the end).

**Solution**: recreate the simlink to my file with config, after that when i run `sudo nginx -t` i see a few errors. So its seems that before this files was empty or something like that, but i didnt notice this because i edit file directly in `sites-available` folder.

Thanks to everybody!

This question helps me to solve the problem: [nginx not listening to port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021481/nginx-not-listening-to-port-80)