# Nginx not listening port 80

Tags: nginx

I run in to issue with setting up v2ray for shadowsocks on linux

Nginx installed to listen port 80, however in logs shows it connecting to completely different port and every time I start shadowsocks port is randomising. Don't understand how to make it listen right port. Ansewrs found here didn't work for me

Nginx default

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
server_name mysite.xyz;
add_header Allow "GET" always;
if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET)$ ) {
return 444;
}
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
root /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.xyz;
index index.html;
}

server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
ssl on;
server_name mysite.xyz;
add_header Allow "GET" always;
if ( $request_method !~ ^(GET)$ ) {
return 444;
}
root /usr/share/nginx/html/mysite.xyz;
index index.html;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/mysite.xyz.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/mysite.xyz.key;
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;
ssl_session_tickets on;
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;
resolver 1.1.1.1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
location / {
proxy_pass http://google.com/;
limit_rate 1000k;
proxy_redirect off;
}
location /v2ray {
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_pass https://localhost:8008;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
}





 shadowsocks-libev.service - Shadowsocks-libev Default Server Service
       Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/shadowsocks-libev.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
       Active: active (running) since Sat 2020-02-01 09:50:04 UTC; 21ms ago
         Docs: man:shadowsocks-libev(8)
     Main PID: 1850 (ss-server)
        Tasks: 2 (limit: 1149)
       Memory: 6.8M
       CGroup: /system.slice/shadowsocks-libev.service
               ├─1850 /usr/bin/ss-server -c /etc/shadowsocks-libev/config.json
               └─1852 v2ray-plugin --fast-open

    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost systemd[1]: Started Shadowsocks-libev Default Server Service.
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: resolving hostname to IPv6 address first
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: using tcp fast open
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: plugin "v2ray-plugin" enabled
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: enable TCP no-delay
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: initializing ciphers... xchacha20-ietf-poly1305
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: using nameserver: 1.1.1.1
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: tcp server listening at [::1]:58343
    Feb 01 09:50:04 localhost ss-server[1850]:  2020-02-01 09:50:04 INFO: tcp port reuse enabled
```

Comment: Hi can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021481/nginx-not-listening-to-port-80 Hope this will help you also this question is same like yours

Comment: Tried. Have a look on my nginx.