# Fail to curl webserver on port 80 (using Nginx)

Tags: nginx, curl, webserver, ipv6

I am unable to connect to my webserver on port 80 when not in localhost, on a debian 9 with nginx 1.14.2. I curl the IPv6 address with

```
curl 'http://[addr]'
```

And I'm welcomed with

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to addr port 80: Connection refused
```

I have the most basic server configuration :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name mywebserver.com www.mywebsever.com; #Those are not the real domain names

    root  /data/www/;
    index index.html;

    location / {
    }
}
```

`tcptraceroute6 addr 80` gives me the following output, so I'm pretty sure it comes from the server :

```
traceroute to addr (addr) from addr, port 80, from port 64245, 30 hops max, 60 bytes packets
 1  rpi4.home (addr)  0.029 ms [closed]  0.014 ms  0.012 ms
```

I disabled ufw and reseted my IPtables using :

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Flushing iptables rules..."
sleep 1
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

But it is still blocked and tcptraceroute6 displays the same error.

My iptables are as follow (`sudo iptables -t nat -nvL`):

```
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 850 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 67 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1 packets, 67 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

Nginx does run :

```
● nginx.service - A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Sat 2021-12-25 23:09:37 UTC; 1h 7min ago
     Docs: man:nginx(8)
  Process: 558 ExecStartPre=/usr/sbin/nginx -t -q -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 562 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on; (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 563 (nginx)
    Tasks: 2 (limit: 4915)
   Memory: 12.5M
   CGroup: /system.slice/nginx.service
           ├─ 563 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
           └─1278 nginx: worker process

Dec 25 23:09:36 rpi4-20210210 systemd[1]: Starting A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server...
Dec 25 23:09:37 rpi4-20210210 systemd[1]: Started A high performance web server and a reverse proxy server.
```

Unforntunately, after running `netstat -ntl`, it appears that the server does not listen to port 80 in IPv6 :

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6010          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6011          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6010                :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6011                :::*                    LISTEN
```

`telnet addr 80` returns :

```
Trying addr...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

I tried adding a rule using `ip6tables -P INPUT ACCEPT`,  `ip6tables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT` and `ip6tables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT` but it does not seems to work right now. I also dropped all IPv6 rules, no changes.

I consulted the following, to this day none worked :

https://serverfault.com/questions/670575/failed-to-connect-to-127-0-0-1-port-80

https://askubuntu.com/questions/676434/port-80-connection-refused

[nginx not listening to port 80](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021481/nginx-not-listening-to-port-80)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I'm just a bit stupid and really not used to webserver configuration, I missed the configuration of my server, it fell on the default nginx server, which is sadly only listening on port 80 on IPv4. Just another dumb mistake, warm thanks for @Petros, who set me om the right tracks.

Comment: I can't do it until tomorrow sadly