# can access django admin through nginx port 80 but not other ports

Tags: django, nginx, docker-compose

I can access Django admin by redirecting traffic from nginx port 80 to django port 8000. However, when I change nginx listen port to 81 I received, after signing in Django admin

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

nginx.conf

```
server {
  listen 81;
  server_name localhost;

  location = /favicon.ico {access_log off;log_not_found off;}

  location /static/ {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    alias /static/;
  }

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://backend:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

docker-compose file

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  backend:
    image: thequy/resume_builder_django:2.0
    build: 
      context: ./backend
      dockerfile: ./docker/django/Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .env
    command: gunicorn resume_builder.wsgi -w ${GUNICORN_WORKER_COUNT} -b 0.0.0.0:${DJANGO_PORT}
    networks:
      - resume_builder_network

  backend_nginx:
    image: thequy/resume_builder_django_nginx:1.0
    build: ./backend/docker/nginx
    ports: 
      - "${BACKEND_DJANGO_PORT}:${BACKEND_DJANGO_PORT}"
    depends_on:
      - backend
    networks:
      - resume_builder_network

networks:
  resume_builder_network:
```

I have changed `BACKEND_DJANGO_PORT=81`.
I tried adding `CORS_ALLOW_ALL_ORIGINS=True` and `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS=["http://backend_nginx:81"]` but it doesn't help

**Edit**: I tried chaning ports of backend_nginx to different values and I realized that the host port must be on port 80, nginx port doesn't matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Django 4.0, origin checking is added in CSRF middleware as mentioned here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/csrf/.

So, if the request generated from a specific domain doesn't match with any trusted origins, it raises `Forbidden (403) CSRF verification failed`.

In your case, you need to set following in `settings.py` (I assume you are running this locally)

```
CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS = ["http://localhost:81"]
```

Now the question arises why it works for 80 port without setting `CSRF_TRUSTED_ORIGINS`, I assume the default 80 port is always trusted, however I can't find any documentation of it.